# append node to an xml in Java

Tags: java, xml, servlets, append

I can't append correctly some info to my xml file. That's the scrivi function

```
    public String scrivi (Document doc, File dest)
   {
     try
     {

        DOMSource sorgente = new DOMSource (doc);
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult (dest);        
        TransformerFactory tf =
            TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transf = tf.newTransformer();
        transf.transform (sorgente, sr);
        return "Tutto ok";
     }
     catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce)
     {

        System.out.println(tce.getMessage());
        return  "<h1> Config </h1>";
     }
     catch (TransformerException te)
     {

        System.out.println(te.getMessage());
        return "<h1> Transformer Errore </h1>";
     }
   }
```

and tath is my code:

```
 try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document document = db.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/azioni.xml"));


            Element root = document.getDocumentElement(); 
            Element new_azione = document.createElement("azione");
            Element id = document.createElement("id_azione");
            id.setTextContent(id_azione);
            Element nome = document.createElement("nome_azione");
            nome.setTextContent(nome_azione);
            Element prezzo_a = document.createElement("prezzo");
            prezzo_a.setTextContent(prezzo);
            new_azione.appendChild(id);
            new_azione.appendChild(nome);
            new_azione.appendChild(prezzo_a);
            document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(new_azione);



            String nomexmlOut="/azioni.xml";



            File filedest = new File(nomexmlOut); 


            out.println(this.scrivi(document, filedest));

}
```

I get the error Transformer Errore ... how can I solve? what's Wrong?
*** UPDATE ***
Error Info

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /azioni.xml (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Show the full error so we can see where it comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell without actual exception trace or message, but my guess is that your problem is the ouput stream.

```
File("/azioni.xml");
```

is not the same as

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/azioni.xml")
```

Try with directing the output to system out and see if it works. i.e. declare scrivi

```
public String scrivi (Document doc, OutputStream out)
```

and call it with

```
scrivi(document, System.out);
```

UPDATE:

To write to the same file location, try something like this (untested)

File out = new File(getClasss().getResource("...").getFile());

and make sure that you close the input stream that you originally read from, before trying to write.

Comment: OK, I was correct, then. You, or the process, doesn't have the permissions to write to / create the output file. Try without the leading slash ('/');

Comment: I replaced the  String nomexmlOut="/azioni.xml"; with  String nomexmlOut="azioni.xml"; but I get the same result java.io.FileNotFoundException: /azioni.xml (Permission denied)

Comment: I'm sure that the file exists because with the  Document document = db.parse(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/azioni.xml")); I can read the file... I need to add a node and update it... that's the problem

Comment: OK, but again, File("/name") is not the same as class.getResource(). See update